# Add nested property to returned record

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a Yesod route handler that returns a JSON with the object

```
{ id: 1,
  title: "foo"
  content: "bar"
}
```

I would like to add a `_links` property with some metadata, that doesn't exist in on the Entity itself, e.g.

```
{ id: 1,
  title: "foo"
  content: "bar"
  _links: {self: http://localhost:3000/events/1}
}
```

How can I add the `_links` to the existing Entity record? Here's my handler:

```
getEventR :: EventId -> Handler Value
getEventR eid = do
    event <- runDB $ get404 eid

    render <- getUrlRender
    let renderedUrl = render $ EventR eid

    let links = object
          [ "self" .= renderedUrl
          ]

    let returnVal = object
          [ "data" .= (Entity eid event)
          , "_links" .= links
          ]

    return returnVal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you'll have to convert your `Entity` to a `Value` manually, then use the functions in `unordered-containers:Data.HashMap.Strict` to insert the `"_links"` key, then build a `Value` out of it again.  Using the lens compatible package for `aeson` could probably simplify this quite a bit though:

```
buildEntityWithLink :: Entity -> Text -> Maybe Value
buildEntityWithLink entity renderedUrl = case toJSON entity of
    Object obj -> 
        let links = object ["self" .= renderedUrl]
            entityWithLink = HashMap.insert "_links" links obj
        in Just (Object entityWithLink)
    _ -> Nothing
```

(I'm assuming that `renderedUrl` has type `Text`, change if needed)

Then you can just pass in your `Entity` and `renderedUrl` to get a new `Value` with the `"_links"` key included.  I've used `Maybe` here to guard against the case where `toJSON :: Entity -> Value` does not return a `Value` with the `Object` constructor.  This will protect you in the future if you change the `Entity` type and how it converts to JSON but forget to update all of your codebase to reflect this change.

EDIT: If you were to use `lens-aeson` You could write it like this, though this requires swapping the argument order just for neatness:

```
buildEntityWithLink :: Text -> Entity -> Value
buildEntityWithLink renderedUrl = (
    over _Object $
         HashMap.insert "_links" $
                        object ["self" .= renderedUrl]
    ) . toJSON
```

This actually lets you drop the `Maybe`, you want to anyway, since the way lenses work means that if the `Object` isn't the top level then the original value is returned, so `buildEntityWithLink "testlink" ([] :: [Entity])` Would just return the same as `toJSON ([] :: [Entity])`, namely an empty `Array`.  The `toJSON` has to be on the outside of the lens operation because in order to compose with `_Object` it has to be able to be a setter, and `toJSON` can't be easily made into a setter.  Instead, we just pre-process our `Entity` into a `Value`, then feed it in to the lens expression.  I've added whitespace where I've lined up the arguments to each function, makes it a bit more readable IMO, but this is all technically 1 line of code.  A useful feature about this implementation is that it's now easy to relax the type signature to `ToJSON a => Text -> a -> Value`, so you can add a `_links` to any type you want to.

Comment: Thanks for this. "Using the lens compatible package for aeson could probably simplify this quite a bit though" -- do you have an example for that, I couldn't find?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [bheklilr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34908965/750039) *working* comment - here's the final code I now have:

```
import Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap (insert)

getEventR :: EventId -> Handler Value
getEventR eid = do
    event <- runDB $ get404 eid

    render <- getUrlRender
    let renderedUrl = render $ EventR eid

    let returnVal = object
          [ "data" .= [buildEntityWithLink (Entity eid event) renderedUrl]]

    return returnVal


buildEntityWithLink :: Entity Event -> Text -> Maybe Value
buildEntityWithLink entity renderedUrl =
    case toJSON entity of
        Object obj ->
            let links = object ["self" .= renderedUrl]
                entityWithLink = HashMap.insert "_links" links obj
            in Just (Object entityWithLink)
        _ -> Nothing
```

And now indeed, the JSON appears as expected with the `self` link