# Map function on a list of entities in handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909930/750039) that adds some data to a Json of an `Entity` before serving it.

Now I would like to apply the same function to a list of entities I got while doing:

```
getEventsR :: Handler Value
getEventsR = do
    events <- runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity Event]
    return $ object ["data" .= events]
```

How can I apply a function with such signature to `events`:

```
addMetaData :: EventId
            -> Event
            -> HandlerT App IO (Maybe Value)
addMetaData eid event = do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the `Traversable` instance.

```
getEventsR :: Handler Value
getEventsR = do
    events <- runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity Event]
    maybeValues <- sequenceA [addMetaData eid event | Entity eid event <- events]
    return ...
```

Either

- `sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative app) => t (app a) -> app (t a)`
- `sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`

should be of use here. (In this example `t ~ []` and `app ~ HandlerT App IO`.)

Comment: damn, I tried to use `sequenceA` before but didn't find an elegant solution as yours :) Thanks!